# Is it possible to statically type a generic C[T] as T in Python?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, pylance, pyright

I am working with SQLite where type hints are still far from perfect, and I ended up with a MCVE of what I think I want to do, and it may be related to statically-typing ABCs.

Example:

```py
T = TypeVar('T')


class ColumnarValue(Generic[T]):
    pass


def test1(guard: ColumnarValue[str]): ...
def test2(guard: ColumnarValue[int]): ...

# These should work
test1("Hello")
test2(42)

# These should be type errors
test1(42)
test2("Hello")

# Or, likewise:
test_assignment_1: ColumnarValue[str] = "this line should typecheck"
test_assignment_2: ColumnarValue[int] = "this line should NOT typecheck"
```

I tried to use ABCs, but since they seem to register using ABC.register(), the typechecker has no clue what I'm talking about.

I also tried generic protocols, but I'd have to engineer a protocol that guards for the functions expected exactly for every type T.

I'm testing this with Pyright/Pylance, but if this is part of the problem, an alternative would be considered an answer.

I also found https://github.com/antonagestam/phantom-types which, according to the documentation, "will not add any processing or memory overhead". This is not completely true since they go through the .parse and `__instancecheck__` protocols on runtime (although they technically don't create any new objects, they do have some overhead in stack frames).

Alas, this is not a static checker, and while the solution there seems to be using `assert isinstance("hello", MyStr)` to ensure that the typechecker can satisfy such guarantees after that line (this works in mypy and pylance at least), it would not trigger any typechecking-time error with `assert isinstance("hello", MyInt)`. The code would fail the assertion at runtime.

Ultimately, I would want to be able to have a type `T` that I can call as `C[T]` so that when I declare a `col_name = Column(String, ...)` in a Model, I can then `col_name = "value"` or some variation of it that is statically checked.

Is this possible, and if it is, where is the magic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to put these columns into a model class in the end, you could use [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#primer) (which is what e.g. the [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator uses under the hood, if you are familiar with that).

A rough sketch:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Any

T = TypeVar("T")


class ColumnarValue(Generic[T]):
    def __get__(self, instance: object, owner: Any) -> T:
        ...

    def __set__(self, instance: object, value: T) -> None:
        ...


class Model:
    some_str_column: ColumnarValue[str]
    some_int_column: ColumnarValue[int]


m = Model()
m.some_str_column = "this line typechecks"
m.some_int_column = "this line does NOT typecheck"
```

---

Also have a look at how sqlalchemy handles all this [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/mypy.html).
In particular the [`Mapped`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Mapped) class, with its actual type definition [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy2-stubs/blob/fd2d9173a62d5e4a8d3f68c9968f103f01eb6ebd/sqlalchemy-stubs/orm/attributes.pyi#L89).